# Async task android onPostExecute

Tags: android

In my android application i use AsyncTask to download the image from internet.

I pass the url and my AsyncTask does the download. But how do i return the bitmap back to my activity. Currently i pass the callback function to my asynctask constructor and in the OnPostExecute i invoke the callback function. Is this the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result you return from `doInBackground` is passed to `onPostExecute` so simple return the bitmap from `doInBackground` method and handle it in `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this:

```
public Bitmap btm;
public void onClick(View v) {
  new DownloadImageTask().execute("http://example.com/image.png");
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
         return loadImageFromNetwork(urls[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
         // set image for ImageView
         mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
         // orsimply save it
         btm = result;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A callback function works fine, you can also pass the Activity in, or an interface. The key thing to watch out for is that activity has not changed or been destroyed.

http://evancharlton.com/thoughts/rotating-async-tasks/ has some good information on AsyncTasks.

Comment: that code is flawed, it doesn't reset the reference in `onDestroy`