# Android AsyncTask (returning an Integer from doInBackground)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, return-value

I'm getting the following errors in the code below: The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask.onPostExecute(Integer). I'm trying to return the result from the http request done in the doInBackground task. I get the error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from AsyncTask to int in the return statement for isAvailable. I feel like there's something simple I'm not doing but I can't quite figure it out.

```
    public int isAvailable(int position) {
        GetIsAvailable isAvail = new GetIsAvailable();
        Integer nisAvail = isAvail.execute(position); // error is still here
        return nisAvail;

    }

    private class GetIsAvailable extends AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Integer > {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer...position) {
            Bundle resBundle = new Bundle();
            String url = "http://www.testurl.com"
                + position[0]+"&uname="+AppStatus.mUserName;
            URL iuri;
            try {
                iuri = new URL(url);
                URLConnection connection = iuri.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        (InputStream) connection.getContent()));
                resBundle.putInt("isAvail", Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim()));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return new Integer(0);

            }

        @Override
        protected Integer onPostExecute(Integer isAvail) { // Main Error here

            return isAvail; 
        }
```

Comment: This could be completely off-base (hey, I'm in class right now, I get a pass, right?) but shouldn't you `return new Integer(0)`?

Comment: Yes, but it appears that I still have the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I think I see the problem. I don't think you can handle this the way you're doing it currently. You should be handling the effects of the value of `isAvail` within the `onPostExecute()` method. `isAvailable()` is running on the main thread, while `isAvail` is running on a separate thread. You're trying to return the result of the AsyncTask before it has finished completion.

I'm 99% sure that's the problem.

Comment: You're right, the AsyncTask doesn't return anything at all and you can't retrieve the result the way it's done right now. The result has to be handled onPostExecute().

Comment: This makes sense and I believe this is the problem but how do you obtain the Integer result in the onPostExecute to return to the main thread?

Comment: Rather than thinking of it that way, think of what you plan to DO with that Integer that is returned. Can that not be handled during `onPostExecute()` instead? `onPostExecute()` runs on the UI thread, so if it's to modify an Activity, it's safe to do so here.

Comment: I've updated the code so that the doInBackground method saves the value of isAvail to the resBundle variable. I'm not modifying an Activity, I just need to return a database value to my main activity. Accessing the database needs to be done within a separate thread to avoid an ANR. I'm not able to get the value back to the main thread (without getting the error: he return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Integer>.onPostExecute(Integer). Does this make sense?

Comment: I think I was finally able to get through the issue. I don't have to return the value. I simply saved the variable to a public class variable as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390605/async-task-android-onpostexecute

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is

```
Integer nisAvail = isAvail.execute(position).get();
```

but then the task is no longer asynchronous as the UI thread has to wait until the AsyncTask finishes.

If you want to keep it asynchronous then you have to handle the result in onPostExecute.

Comment: +1 for mentioning AsyncTask.get(), it is doable but not a good practice, as calling AsyncTask.get() on UI thread block thread execution and probably get ANR exception.

Answer (score 1):

This return an int:

```
return Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
```

this return an int as well:

```
return 0;
```

You must return an Integer:

```
return new Integer(br.readLine().trim());

return new Integer(0);
```

Comment: This is true, but I still have the same error: cannot convert from AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Integer> to Integer and cannot convert from AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Integer> to Integer (I've updated my code to include the changes)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get value returned from `doInBackground` method.
Then do this:

```
Integer Value = AsyncTaskClass.execute(ParamsIfSpecified).get();
```

Comment: add some explanation here to describe your answer

Comment: i have made it explanatory @Unni Kris